# Running FFMPEG command through Golang exec

Tags: go, ffmpeg

I need to run an [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) command to create a video from images with a crossfade between images as the transition. The command is derived from this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg/834035). I need to run it through the Golang [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package. The command I need to run is:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-0.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-2.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v];[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map '[v]' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -crf 1 -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

If you run this command directly in the terminal, it works just fine. However, it does not work through my code. This is my code that takes a string command and runs it through the [os/exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) package:

```
command := "ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-0.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-1.png -loop 1 -t 5 -i img-2.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v];[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map '[v]' -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -s 1280x720 -aspect 16:9 -crf 1 -preset ultrafast output.mp4"

lastQuote := rune(0)
f := func(c rune) bool {
    switch {
    case c == lastQuote:
        lastQuote = rune(0)
        return false
    case lastQuote != rune(0):
        return false
    case unicode.In(c, unicode.Quotation_Mark):
        lastQuote = c
        return false
    default:
        return unicode.IsSpace(c)
    }
}
parts := strings.FieldsFunc(command, f)

cmd := exec.Command(parts[0], parts[1:]...)
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

When I run this, I get the ffmpeg error: No such filter: '"', Error configuring filters. I know it has something to do with the quotes that HAVE to be in the video filters, but I have tried everything to get it to work and I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your fields func isn't removing the enclosing quotes. Instead of trying to lex the shell input, why not use a package that does it properly, or just pass the string off to a shell to execute?

Comment: I've tried to run the command without the enclosing quotes around the filter complex because even that works directly from the terminal but I get this error: Missing ')' or too many args in 'gte(T'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x3b94ee0] Error initializing filter 'blend' with args 'all_expr=A*(if(gte(T'
Error configuring filters.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that switch but my feeling is that you shouldn't have any of that. Just pass "ffmpeg" as the first argument then use the backticks that let you make string literals (can't do it here cause the markup makes it into a code snippet) so you can keep the quotes necessary in the command and pass everything after ffmpeg as a single string instead of parting it out and trying to spread the array with `parts[1:]...`. I think you're just making more work than is necessary unless you really need to fine tune those args.

Comment: That switch keeps arguments that might have a space within them together as one argument by honoring surrounding quotations.

Comment: Quoting an argument in the shell doesn't pass the quotes to the program. Again, you can either lex it properly, or just let a shell run the command for you.

Comment: Regardless if you think I'm doing it completely wrong, it doesn't work. That's the purpose of the question. I have tried multiple ways of getting this to work. You've given 2 possible solutions without any examples.

Answer (score 7):

This actually does work correctly :

```
exec.Command("ffmpeg", "-loop", "1", "-t", "5", "-i", "img-0.png", "-loop",  "1", "-t", "5", "-i", "img-1.png", "-loop", "1", "-t", "5", "-i", "img-2.png", "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b1v];[2:v][1:v]blend=all_expr='A*(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5))+B*(1-(if(gte(T,0.5),1,T/0.5)))'[b2v];[0:v][b1v][1:v][b2v][2:v]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-c:v", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-r", "30", "-s", "1280x720", "-aspect", "16:9", "-crf", "1", "-preset", "ultrafast", "output.mp4")
```

Notice that I did remove start and end double quotes from the `-filter_complex` parameters and two single quotes from the `-map` parameters.

Did it by hand, though, not sure of a `strings` function that could do it *automagically*.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @MurtadhaS. did you manage to find a solution for this? using strings.replace doesn't work